# How to bypass cloudflare caching like reddit does

Tags: cloudflare

Someone knows how reddit manages to bypass cloudflare static html caching once the user logs in successfully with a reload of page?

I see that the current page gets reloaded after a successful login.

Response headers before login:

```
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
CF-RAY: 23b76b8270950e30-MXP
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20794
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2015 16:08:27 GMT
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Firefox-Spdy: 3.1
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-moose: majestic
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Response headers after login:

```
CF-RAY: 23b76cb065140e30-MXP
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0, max-age=0, must-revalidate, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 18697
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2015 16:09:16 GMT
Expires: -1
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Vary: accept-encoding
X-Firefox-Spdy: 3.1
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-moose: majestic
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172826-Can-dynamic-sites-work-with-CloudFlare-

Answer (score 10):

There are two key ways of doing this with CloudFlare:

- In CloudFlare you can set a page rule to avoid caching files of your choice.
- You can serve no-cache headers which CloudFlare will respect.

## In order to set-up a Page Rule

1. Go to your CloudFlare dashboard and select Page Rules
2. Add a Page Rule which matches **yourdomain.com/*.html*
3. Set cache level to bypass
4. Save and deploy

[image: Page Rule with Cache Level Bypass]

## Set Cache Headers

CloudFlare's Help Centre explains [how to control cache through the headers sent from the origin](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-CloudFlare-What-to-Cache-):

> The second way to alter what CloudFlare will cache is through caching
>   headers sent from the origin. CloudFlare will respect these settings
>   (but only for files with the extensions that we cache by default),
>   unless a Page Rule is set to cache everything and an edge cache
>   expires TTL is set. Here are the caching headers we consider:
>
> - If the Cache-Control header is set to "private", "no-store", "no-cache",  or "max-age=0", or if there is a cookie in the response,
>     then CloudFlare will not cache the resource.
> - Otherwise, if the Cache-Control header is set to "public" and the "max-age" is greater than 0, or if the Expires headers are set any
>     time in the future, we will cache the resource.
>
> Note: As per RFC rules, "Cache-Control: max-age" trumps "Expires"
>   headers. If we see both and they do not agree, max-age wins.

In PHP you can implement this using the header function as follows:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```